# Unable to save (download) image file to iOS device using gallery_saver 2.3.2

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio

I get his message in the terminal when trying to download an image from my flutter app using gallery_saver 2.3.2:

flutter: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-app.appspot.com/o/user_image%2FA2cPGwK2J0T9c2JeKXXXXX.jpg?alt=media&token=d25fabd2-2902-4a93-8571-XXXXX
flutter: null
flutter: File size:129453
flutter: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9BDFD985-E381-4A45-B2E9-326AF00D63E8/Library/Caches/user_image%2FA2cPGwK2J0T9c2JeKXXXXX.jpg?alt=media&token=d25fabd2-2902-4a93-8571-XXXXX

It created a folder in the device Album but doesn't contain any images after trying to download the images, nor can I find them on any of the obvious folder locations.

It seems to only be an iOS issue, as works fine on Android.

Code of the widget that handles the image download:

```
GestureDetector(
                                  child: _downloading
                                      ? Container(
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                            color: Colors.purple,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : RowButton(
                                          icon: Icons.download,
                                        ),
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _downloading = true;
                                    });
                                    _downloading = true;
                                    String url = widget.userPicId;
                                    await GallerySaver.saveImage(url,
                                        albumName: 'MyApp');
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                        .showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(
                                        content: Text(
                                            "Downloaded to 'MaApp' folder",
                                            textScaleFactor: 1.2),
                                        duration:
                                            const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                        backgroundColor: Colors
                                            .deepPurpleAccent
                                            .withOpacity(0.6),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                    setState(() {
                                      _downloading = false;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
```

Comment: Previous error message which might offer some clue:

Comment: flutter: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DD7E0E28/Library/Caches/user_image%2Fl1oe.jpg?alt=media&token=af-a1
CoreData: XPC: XPC connection was invalidated
[error] error: XPC: synchronousRemoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler encountered error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service created from an endpoint was invalidated: failed to check-in, peer may have been unloaded: mach_error=10000003." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service created from an endpoint was invalidated: failed to check-in, peer may have been unloaded: mach_error=10000003.}